# How can I add a zero at the start of an array after each loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

```
delta_soil_initial = ones(1, num_steps) + delta -1; %initial soil thickness
delta_soil_matrix = zeros(num_steps, num_steps); % Initialize matrix to store delta_soil values

% Update soil thickness
delta_soil_initial = delta_soil_initial - f_z .* t_i;

% Store delta_soil values for this step
delta_soil_matrix(i, :) = delta_soil_initial;

% Remove the last element from f_z
f_z(end) = [];
delta_soil_initial(1) = [];
```

I would like to store delta_soil values for each loop in a matrix, however, the array shrinks after every loop. To compensate, I would like to add a 0 at the start of every loop. For example, 1st loop: 0, 0.23, 0.67.... 2nd loop: *0*, 0, 0.21, 0.58... The first loop gives the desired results, however, for subsequent loops I would need to add a zero at the strart to make it make sense. Thanks!

I've tried using circshift and also removing the last element from the matrix (not allowed anyway), but this did not work.

Comment: You mention matrix and as well array. Can you add more details and make sure it is more clear for readers?

Comment: Also, what loop? Could you please post a [mre]?

Comment: The loop you mention is unclear, but this might be helpful. (i) instead of truncating `delta_soil_initial`, why not just replace the first element with 0? (ii) You can put a zero at the start of a vector using `delta_soil_initial = [0, delta_soil_initial]`. Maybe you can use this line of code in the loop you are talking about

Comment: You _pre-allocate_ your result matrix at the right final size and full of zeros. Then when you run your algorythm/loop, you only update the relevant part of this result matrix. This way any matrix position you do not assign will already contain a zero.